# Webpack - npm run start and build doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am used to create react projects using **create-react-app** but i decided to create one without it but i am stuck in **webpack** configuration as i am new to it:

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "server": "^1.0.30",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js file:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLplugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node-modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node-modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
]

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', index.js),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/build')
    },
    module: {rules},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './public/index.html'})
    ]
}
```

**.babelrc.json file:**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

this is my whole project folders and files tree:

[image]

When i run `npm run start` or `npm run build`, it fails:

with `npm run start`, i get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\saher\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\saher\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

With `npm run build`:

```
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: index is not defined
```

I am new to webpack and i can't figure out where the problem is, i think i have installed all files and configurations required to make it work, so where is the problem exactly??

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @JoshBonnick yes!

Comment: also, ensure you are in the project folder when issuing that command from the terminal. You might consider using the nom plug in where you can just click on the script to run.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i am in the right directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug report stating webpack-server 3.11 is not compatible with with  webpack-cli v4.

The report can be found here: [Issue 2759](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759)

> Yes - webpack-dev-server does not work with webpack-cli v4

Link to comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759#issuecomment-706668920

The solution is to revamp your `project.json` file by changing to compatible versions (and welcome to Webpack :-) )

Comment: Thank you, now i can use just `webpack serve` to run the server without the need to use compatible versions

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, you wrote index without string quotes.

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', index.js)
```

This should be

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
```

It is like a variable when you write without string quotes. You can try the same this on console.log.

[image]

Because index is not defined.

Comment: Thank you this solved half of the problem, now `npm run build` works but `npm run start` produce the same error

Answer (score 0):

`"main": "index.js"` in `package.json` should be `"main" : "src/index.js"`

Comment: It seems to be failing because it cant find it's entry point